# Remove duplicates xslt/xpath

Tags: xslt, sharepoint, xpath

The XML and  xsl below selects items as expected but produces duplicates My problem is how to remove duplicates, if there are any categories with the same name?

XML

```
    <div><b>Departments:</b>Supevisor</div>
    <div><b>Location:</b> <a >Treausry</a></div>
    <div><b>Cat:</b> <a >Trials</a></div>
    <div><b>Months:</b></div>
    </Documents>


   <Documents>
    <div><b>Departments:</b>Supevisor</div>
    <div><b>Location:</b> <a >Treausry</a></div>
    <div><b>Cat:</b> <a >Best</a></div>
    <div><b>Months:</b></div>
    </Documents>




   <Documents>
      <div><b>Departments:</b>News Week</div>
    <div><b>Location:</b> <a >Treausry</a></div>
    <div><b>Cat:</b> <a >Test 2</a></div>
    <div><b>Months:</b></div>
    </Documents>

       <Documents>

    <div><b>Departments:</b>Senior</div>
    <div><b>Location:</b> <a >Banking</a></div>
    <div><b>Cat:</b> <a >Trials</a></div>
    <div><b>Months:</b></div>
    </Documents>
```

XSL am using

```
<xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
                <xsl:sort select="@Cat" order="ascending"></xsl:sort>
                <xsl:if test="@Store != '' and @Location != ''">
                    <li>
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="contains($PageUrl,concat('Store=',@Store, '&amp;','Location=',@Location, '&amp;', 'Months=',@Months))">
                            <div>
                            <a href="{concat('#tabs-',@ID)}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="self::*/@Cat"></xsl:value-of>
                            </a>
                            </div>
                                 </xsl:when>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </li>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
```

Output now

```
<documents>
    Supervisor
     Treasury


 Supervisor
     Best


News Week
     Treasury

Senior
     Treasury
```

Expected Output

```
<documents>
    Supervisor
     Treasury
     Best


News Week
     Treasury

Senior
     Treasury
```

Thanks

Comment: There are numerous examples on StackOverflow on how to do this. [Check out this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18830050/1078110) and see if that doesn't answer your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSLT and xpath v1.0 find duplicates and aggregate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18828456/xslt-and-xpath-v1-0-find-duplicates-and-aggregate)

Comment: Grouping and duplicates elimination are much easier with XSLT 2.0 than with XSLT 1.0. The solutions are quite different so you need to say which version you are using.

Comment: Thanks for your answers which did lead me to a right understanding, but I want to select preceding sibling after a filter.

This is how far I have got, 
<xsl:if test="self::*/@Cat=following::*/@Cat">
   <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::*/@Cat[1]=[self::*/@StoreCat=following::*/@StoreCat]"/>
</xsl:if>

I am getting a syntax error, please help