# XPath duplicates syntax error

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I am using the XSL below to test if self axis exists in the following axis, if it does, then select the first preceding value. I am getting a syntax error help please. Reference to what I am trying to achieve:

[Remove duplicates xslt/xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19409642/remove-duplicates-xslt-xpath)

```
<xsl:if test="self::*/@Cat=following::*/@Cat">
   <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::*/@Cat[1]=[self::*/@Cat=following::*/@Cat]"/>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: there are no attributes "@Cat" in the source shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19409642/remove-duplicates-xslt-xpath --> please give us the source XML. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Peter, I am not I understand what you mean, but that is all of my xml.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error is the square brackets around the expression that follows "[1]=".

Are you sure you want to be using "following" rather than "following-sibling"?

Also, if there is an attribute @Cat then there will only be one such attribute, so selecting the first is pointless.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I don't thinking I am asking questions right as I keep going round in loop, and am new to xslt. 

This is what I want to achieve. I want to select all @Cat nodes based on a pageurl filter. Once that is done, group the duplicates selected just by selecting first value. I have asked a series of questions just to achieve this but no joy. Any help will be appreciated on how to achieve this.

Comment: Grouping in XSLT 1.0 is quite tricky, but most XSLT books will have a section describing how to do it: look up "Muenchian grouping". Or move to XSLT 2.0 if you possibly can, where the xsl:for-each-group construct makes it trivial. However, your code sample suggests that you might be trying to run before you can walk; it's easier to learn a language if you start by tackling easier problems!